# Dice Rolling Probability Distribution Question

Tags: statistics

Suppose I two 6 sided die and let M = the maximum of the two rolls, the PDF in that case would look something like $$(\frac{k}{6})^{2} (1-(\frac{k-1}{k})^{2})$$

However, lets say that I now want to roll two sets of die. ie, I roll one set of die, take the maximum, roll another set of die then take the maximum and finally I want to take the minimum of the two maximums. I'm not really sure how I should go about this?

Im assuming the pdf for the getting the maximum of the two sets of die would look something like this $$(\frac{k}{6})^{4} (1-(\frac{k-1}{k})^{4})$$ (please correct me if I'm wrong). I'm just really confused about taking the minimum now of the two maximums.

Comment: Do you mean $\left(\frac{k}{6}\right)^{2} \left(1-\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^{2}\right)$?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, sorry I'll change it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, though it's rather complicated.  We have $$\left(\frac{k}{6}\right)^{2} \left(1-\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^{2}\right)=\left(\frac k6\right)^2-\left(\frac {k-1}6\right)^2$$

In this form, it's easy to see that it's correct.  It's the probability that both dice show $\leq k$ minus the probability that both show $\leq k-1$.

To compute the PDF for the minimum of the two maxima, we first need the cdf.  The probability that the maximum is $\leq k$ is
$$\left[\left(\frac16\right)^2-\left(\frac06\right)^2\right]+
\left[\left(\frac26\right)^2-\left(\frac16\right)^2\right]+\cdots+
\left[\left(\frac k6\right)^2-\left(\frac {k-1}6\right)^2\right]$$
It's easy to see that this sum telescopes to $$\frac {k^2}{36}$$
Now if the minimum of the two maxima is $k$, we have either that the maximum of the first roll is $k$ and the maximum of the second roll is $>k$, or the maximum of the second is $k$ and that of the first is $>k$ or the maximum of both is $k$.

This is $$2\left(\left(\frac k6\right)^2-\left(\frac {k-1}6\right)^2\right)\left(1-\frac{k^2}{36}\right)+\left(\left(\frac k6\right)^2-\left(\frac {k-1}6\right)^2\right)^2$$

**EDIT**

The above simplifies to $$\frac{2k-1}{36}$$ according to a CAS.  As a sanity check $$\sum_{k=1}^6\frac{2k-1}{36}=1$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The first step seems clear to me, but I don't understand how this will result in the pdf of taking the maximum of the two separate rolls. For example, if I roll two die and get (2,4) then M1 = 4, then I roll another two die and get (1,2) then M2 = 2. I then want to take the minimum of (M1,M2)=2. I'm not really sure how this explains the PDF of the above example?

Comment: @Tropical   I'm sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough.  I thought you wanted to take the maximum of maxima.  (That's what you actually computed.)  I think the question of the minimum of the maxima is harder.  Give me a few minutes to see if I can do it.